# Magento: how to use two theme for single store view(and single website)

Tags: magento-1.7

i need two theme for single store view. is this possible ???

Magento: different theme, but using same store view ????.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research i found my one question answer :

If you want to change your Magento’s store theme without changing URL(no multi store, no multi website) and simply use this code snippet.

1. create one function ex. changeTheme('Theme-name'); and run this function with your requirement
2. add this function in your head.phtml after php start.

   ```
    function changeTheme($themeName)
    {
      Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend') //Area (frontend|adminhtml)
                       ->setPackageName('default') //Name of Package
                       ->setTheme($themeName); // Name of theme
    }
   ```

enjoy :)